# click on an expand & collapse button selenium cucumber eclipse

Tags: eclipse, selenium, automated-tests, cucumber

I am trying to click on an expand/collapse button and my first code is working for one of the buttons but somehow it is not working for the other two. It is the same structure that is why it is making this as a strange problem.

Html 1

```
<!-- language: lang-html -->

<button class="collapser__header collapsed " type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseIndkomstrubrikker" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseIndkomstrubrikker">Anden indkomst</button>

<div class="collapse" id="collapseIndkomstrubrikker"></div>

<!-- end snippet -->
```

**Code which is not working**

```
case "Anden indkomst": 
            try {
                WebElement wb;
                JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
                    wb = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@data-target='#collapseIndkomstrubrikker']"));
                    js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", wb);
                } catch (Exception b) {
                   throw new NoSuchElementException("kunne ikke finde " + knap);

                }
            break;
```

Html 2

```html
<button class="collapser__header collapsed " type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseFradragrubrikker" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseFradragrubrikker">Andre fradrag</button>

<div class="collapse" id="collapseFradragrubrikker"></div>
```

Code 2 which is working

```
case "Andre fradrag": 
            try {
                WebElement wb;
                JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
                    wb = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@data-target='#collapseFradragrubrikker']"));
                    js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", wb);
                } catch (Exception b) {

               throw new NoSuchElementException("kunne ikke finde " + knap);
            }
        break;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was smth wrong with my Eclipse which is the reason why my code didn't work in the first place. When I restarted Eclipse the code worked:)

Answer (score 0):

change 
 wb = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='collapseIndkomstrubrikker']"));
to 
wb = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@data-target='#collapseIndkomstrubrikker']"));
like the second example

Comment: I did that as well and it didnt work. This is the secodn thing I tried. Tried so many options but somehow it doesn't work

Comment: try it with a different WebElement

Answer (score 0):

Try to use WebDriverWait to wait for element be clickable as below:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
WebElement wb;
wb = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//*[@data-target='#collapseIndkomstrubrikker']"))); 
js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", wb);
```